# Android how to set scrollbar to GalleryView

Tags: android

I want to set scrollbar to GalleryView, Horizontally, i tried many ways and it is not showing up, how can i do that ?

```
  <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true">
        <Gallery 
            android:id="@+id/gridView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"

            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:scrollX="190dp"
             />

        </ScrollView>
```

Comment: have you tried putting the whole gallery layout inside a scrollview?

Comment: yes and still the same